# Funcionalidade do !IsPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

Qual a real utilidade deste if(!IsPostBack) do page_load das páginas aspx?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(!IsPostBack)
 {
  //codigo
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa condição serve para que o conteúdo dentro desse if só seja executado na primeira vez que a Página for carregada, pois no ASPX toda vez que você interage com a página ele faz o PostBack.

Comment: quais tipos de interação?

Comment: @PedroBelino Por exemplo clicar num botão que faz um post pro servidor, exemplo: um formulário, a referência que usei foi essa thread aqui na [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/e2e5d7d6-8774-4c15-8cac-e51c3e934f52/ispostback?forum=aspnetpt)

Comment: Toda vez que você interage na página que precise de uma resposta do servidor como  submeter um formulário gera um postback.

Answer (score 1):

No .net WebForms há 2 flags que indicam de que forma foi feito a request para a sua página. São elas: `IsPostBack` e `IsCallback`.

Essas duas flags são utilizadas para implementar lógicas para seu código, através do tipo de `request` que você está recebendo.

Segue um exemplo de  como você pode identificar suas requests:

`!IsPostBack` & `!IsCallback`: Indica que sua `request` foi feita através do verbo `HTTP GET` e possivelmente é a primeira vez que ela está sendo carregada.

`!IsPostBack` & `!IsCallback`: Indica que sua `request` foi feita através do verbo `HTTP POST` e provavelmente não é a primeira vez que sua página está sendo carregada.

`!IsPostBack` & `IsCallback`: Indica que sua `request` foi disparada por um evento 
`CallBack` implementado em sua página.